# Согласование подлежащего и сказуемого

Tags: согласование, сказуемые, подлежащее, количественно-именное-сочетание

Путаюсь при согласовании подлежащего со сказуемым, если подлежащее - числительное. Как правильно:

> На средства администрации были
> заменены 8 опор (или было)
>
> Было выявлено двое безработных граждан
> (или выявлены).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитайте, чтоб не путаться:

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=bolshinstvo

Сейчас всё больше согласовывают по смыслу. Если важна совокупность, цифра, то единств. число, если приоритетна активность каждого, то множественное:

Я бы расставила так: На средства администрации было заменено 8 опор. Важно, что деньги потрачены не зря, каждая опора меня не интересует;

Были выявлены двое безработных граждан. - важна судьба каждого, это личности. Но и ед. число возможно, если не делать акцент на личностях, а только на совокупности.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку и за ответ

Comment: Интересно, а почему Вы не принимаете ответы? У Вас всего 3% принятых.

Comment: Извините, просто забываю.